# Block Jira opening ticket if custom field value is less than 1 using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jira

i need to block the creation of an issue on Jira if a custom field value is less than 1.

I tried with this code with no success, the custom field ID is: 13200.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.opensymphony.workflow.InvalidInputException;
import org.apache.log4j.Category;


import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder;
import com.atlassian.jira.config.properties.APKeys;

def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def cField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_13200")
def cFieldValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cField) as Integer


if (cFieldValue > 0){
log.debug("ERRORE, QUANTITA' NON DISPONIBILI");
throw "ERRORE";
throw new InvalidInputException("QUANTITA' NON DISPONIBILI");
return cFieldValue;
return false;
}
```

That custom field is taken from another DB (linked via Elements) and it's the quantity of a particular item, if the quantity is less than 0 the ticket should throw an exception but it doesnt work as i would, giving me this error in the LOG:

```
For input string: "{"keys":["47"]}"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{"keys":["47"]}"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
```

The taken value is right (47) but maybe it's in a wrong type?

Can anybody help me?

Thank you,
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable content is "{"keys":["47"]}" , not "47". You can see this here: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{"keys":["47"]}"

that's why you get this exception, as "{"keys":["47"]}" cannot be converted to a number, so please double-check the value of the variable you are converting to a number

Comment: Thank you for your input!

You were right, it was picking the entire thing, so i tried with this:

`def cFieldValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cField)
def casting_cFieldvalue = cFieldValue.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")
def valore_intero = casting_cFieldvalue.toInteger()`

But i receive this:

**java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Throwable
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Throwable**



Any idea about it? I'm searching in Google too btw .. Thank you again

Comment: what is the output of `println casting_cFieldvalue`, and `println  casting_cFieldvalue.getClass()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.opensymphony.workflow.InvalidInputException

def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def Scorte = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_13200")
def ValoreScorte = issueObject.getCustomFieldValue(Scorte)
def QuantitaRichiesta = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_13201")
def ValoreQuantitaRichiesta = issueObject.getCustomFieldValue(QuantitaRichiesta)
def casting_ValoreScorte = ValoreScorte.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "") 
def Scorte_Intero = casting_ValoreScorte as int
def QuantitaRichiesta_Intero = ValoreQuantitaRichiesta as int

if (Scorte_Intero <= 0 || QuantitaRichiesta_Intero > Scorte_Intero){
log.debug("ERRORE, QUANTITA' NON DISPONIBILI")
throw new InvalidInputException("","QUANTITA' NON DISPONIBILI")
}
```

This is the final code :) Thank you for your help!